# How do i get someones profile picture to display back to them?

Tags: facebook, profile, image

How do i get someones profile picture to diplay back to me. I have already gotten permissions to use the user's pictures etc i just don't know how to use their profile picture and display it back to them.

Any help would be awesome

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Calling on the Graph API

http://graph.facebook.com/[id]/picture

The following will give you different sizes

```
http://graph.facebook.com/[id]/picture?type=square

http://graph.facebook.com/[id]/picture?type=normal

http://graph.facebook.com/[id]/picture?type=large
```

So you can just put these URLs straight in an `<img>` tag

EG: `<img src="http://graph.facebook.com/4/picture?type=square" />`

See:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/#pictures

These are in the public domain, so there is no need for any authentication.